# ios Calling back viewController from different class

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, viewcontroller

I have problems calling back my viewController from nsobject class. Here my code:

ViewController:

```
-(void)startTest:(NSString*)testToRun
{
    ViewController *ViewController = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    SecondClass *secondClass = [[SecondClass alloc] init];
    secondClass.viewController = viewController;
    [secondClass doSomething];
}

-(void) createView
{
    UIView *newView = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[self.view bounds];
    self.newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:newView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:newView]
}


NSObject classe:

.h file

#import "ViewController.h"

@class ViewController;

@interface SecondClass : NSObject
{
    ViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) ViewController *viewController;

-(void) doSomething;


.m file

-(void) doSomething
{
    [viewController createView];

}
```

any of you may know what I'm doing wrong or how can I call back my view controller from my nsobject class?

Comment: Check to see that viewController actually still exists and isn't nil when you call it.

Comment: at the moment of passing the pointer from the view controller to the nsboject class is not nill but when is in the nsobject class is nil and I don't understand why

Comment: @Jeff, I'm not using ARC

Comment: Are you synthesizing your own get/setters on this or just using the auto-matically generated ones?

Comment: At some point, you need to give your TestRunner class instance a pointer to your ViewController object. I'd recommend putting up the full code for the two classes, as well as the full code that creates the TestRunner and ViewController instance, that way people can check that you're passing the necessary pointers between them. Just because you've declared a property for the ViewController in your TestRunner, doesn't mean that something else has come along and given your TestRunner instance a valid pointer for that property.

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to the *instance variable* `viewController` but are assigning the *property* `viewController`.

The property is automatically synthesized to an instance variable called `_viewController` by default. You can change this to explicitly synthesize to your instance variable, but the more canonical thing to do is to use the default `_viewController` and refer to it as `self.viewController` within your implementation file.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Unless you've got other code somewhere handling the getter/setting, this is your issue HelenaM.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the code below

```
-(void)startTest:(NSString*)testToRun
{
    ViewController *ViewController = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    SecondClass *secondClass = [[SecondClass alloc] init];
    secondClass.viewController = viewController;
    [secondClass doSomething];
}
```

I believe the above piece of code is defined in `ViewController` itself, so you should be doing the following

```
-(void)startTest:(NSString*)testToRun
{
    //ViewController *ViewController = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; Don't do this, it is already initialized
    SecondClass *secondClass = [[SecondClass alloc] init];
    secondClass.viewController = self;//assign self as reference
    [secondClass doSomething];
}
```

For more perfection you can also try using `Protocols`.

Comment: if I using secondClass.viewController = self; The instance of viewController in the secondClass is nil.